# rendering plotly in Shiny correctly, only 1 of multiple plots rendering

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

Running the below code as a `app.r` renders a ggplotly for `p2` in a shiny app, but not `p1`, though `p1` does render in the RStudio plot pane. I want to be able to get plotly plots of `p1` and `p2` in the app and on Shiny. What am I missing?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(1:100)
y <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()


ui <- fluidPage(
            fluidRow(
              column(width=8,
                     radioButtons("radioInput", "Radio Button Header", choices =
                                    c("name of plot 1 for user" = "plot 1",
                                      "name of plot 2 for user" = "plot 2"
                                  )   )
                    )
            ),             
            plotlyOutput("distPlot", height="700px")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({

if (input$radioInput == "plot 1")  {
  p1 <- ggplotly(p1)
  print(p1)}   
if (input$radioInput == "plot 2")  {
  p2 <- ggplotly(p2)
  print(p2)}  

 })
}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Without `plotly` (removing `ggplotly` calls and changing `plotlyOutput` back to `plotOutput`, and `renderPlotly` back to `renderPlot`), Shiny plots both:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(1:100)
y <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()


ui <- fluidPage(
fluidRow(
column(width=8,
       radioButtons("radioInput", "Radio Button Header", choices =
                      c("name of plot 1 for user" = "plot 1",
                        "name of plot 2 for user" = "plot 2"
                      )   )
 )
),             
 plotOutput("distPlot", height="700px")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

if (input$radioInput == "plot 1")  {

  print(p1) }   
if (input$radioInput == "plot 2")  {

  print(p2)}  

})
}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `else if`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(1:100)
y <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width=8,
           radioButtons("radioInput", "Radio Button Header", choices =
                          c("name of plot 1 for user" = "plot 1",
                            "name of plot 2 for user" = "plot 2"
                          )   )
    )
  ),             
  plotlyOutput("distPlot", height="700px")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({

    if (input$radioInput == "plot 1")  {
      p1 <- ggplotly(p1)
      print(p1) }   
    else if (input$radioInput == "plot 2")  {
      p2 <- ggplotly(p2)
      print(p2)}  

  })
}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: that worked, fantastic. but, curious why the original structure (just `if`  and no `if else`) works for regular non-ggplotly plots?  - just added that above.

Comment: Tbh am not sure why - but have noticed the same behaviour myself in the past, there's something within the plotly implementation I guess.